# what to do on Windows 10 S mode

Tags: xetex

I have now a Surface Go running Windows 10 S mode.  I will not switch it out of S mode since I want it to run fast and clean.  But it seems there is no way to run LaTeX now.  But I need to do this.  Are there any options?

Comment: Short of having someone create a proper TeX distribution as a "Windows App" for the MS Store (or whatever it is called) I can only see online TeX editors like Overleaf working.

Comment: A short search for LaTeX in the MS Store turned up one LaTeX editor (no compliation), one LaTeX editor that uses an online service to compile (so you need an internet connection) and one system called "LawTeX", which seems to render documents, but say "LawTeX does not aim to replace other TeX distributions. It works best for academic papers but not fancy TeX features: to write the document, not publishing them. For publication, one still needs traditional pdfTeX to generate high qualify printable output." in the description.